# Next.js Prisma can't reach docker postgresql error

Tags: postgresql, docker, next.js

I want to dockerize my Next.js full stack app. But it gives me: Please make sure your database server is running at `db`:`5433`.

I have tried everything like change db name to localhost, db, pgdb and etc. None of them are working

```
FROM node:18-alpine AS base

# Install dependencies only when needed
FROM base AS deps
# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies based on the preferred package manager
COPY package.json yarn.lock* package-lock.json* pnpm-lock.yaml* ./
RUN \
    if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn --frozen-lockfile; \
    elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm ci; \
    elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then corepack enable pnpm && pnpm i --frozen-lockfile; \
    else echo "Lockfile not found." && exit 1; \
    fi

# Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM base AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

# Next.js collects completely anonymous telemetry data about general usage.
# Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/telemetry
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry during the build.
# ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN \
    if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn run build; \
    elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm run build; \
    elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then corepack enable pnpm && pnpm run build; \
    else echo "Lockfile not found." && exit 1; \
    fi

# Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM base AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry during runtime.
# ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs

COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public

# Set the correct permission for prerender cache
RUN mkdir .next
RUN chown nextjs:nodejs .next

# Automatically leverage output traces to reduce image size
# https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000
# set hostname to localhost
ENV HOSTNAME "0.0.0.0"

# server.js is created by next build from the standalone output
# https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/output
CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

This is my docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  app:
    container_name: frontend
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
    restart: always

  db:
    container_name: pgdb
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: docker
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U postgres"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
```

How can I solve this problem ? I can connect to postgresql with pgAdmin after container up with using localhost as a db name and 5433 as port;

Comment: I suspect that you get your error during the build phase? Prisma needs the database to be up during the build phase and docker compose doesn't start the database until the run-time phase. I haven't found a way to solve this without doing the image build manually.

Comment: nope, I can use RUN npx prisma generate in build phase. But when I enter my website I get database can not reach error. Also I can not RUN npx prisma migrate dev or npx prisma migrate deploy :(

Comment: RUN statements are executed during the build phase. If they fail, you don't have a valid image to run in the run phase. Your last statement indicates that your RUN statements fail?

Comment: RUN npx prisma generate <- when I use like that it's not failed. I successfully create my containers. But when I want to use npx prisma migrate deploy it's failed. That's why I want to use it after build process but then I get prisma can not reach error, when I try it with pgAdmin I can successfully connect docker postgresql

Comment: It might be a timing issue where your backend tries to connect to the database before the database is ready. Try running `docker compose up -d` twice. If your container successfully starts on the second try, it's probably a timing issue.

Comment: Main problem is here, when I run it like npm run dev. It works very well. I wrote     healthcheck for timing issue. App is waiting until postgresql is online